# Странно работает функция в Python

Tags: python, функции, python-3.6

Пишу небольшую утилиту для изменения конфигов. Мне понадобилось получать значения из файла и я написал функцию которая это делает, но суть проблемы не в этом. При вызове функции в первые разы, все работает как надо, но потом, когда я её вызываю с точно такими же аргументами, она не возвращает ничего, а точнее "". Возможно ли такое:

```py
def FindValue(file, var):
    fileCont = file.readlines()
    for line in fileCont:
        if re.match(var, line):
            splittedLine = re.split(" ", line)
            out = ""
            for word in splittedLine:
                if word == var:
                    continue
                else:
                    out +=" "
                    out += word
            break
    try:
        out = re.sub("\n", " ", out)
    except:
        return ""

    outList = []
    for sym in out:
        outList.append(sym)
    outList.remove(" ")
    out=""
    for sym in outList:
        out+=sym
    print(out)
    return out

if FindValue(self.asset, "ID") != " " and FindValue(self.asset, "ID") != "":
    self.ID = FindValue(self.asset, "ID")
```

Я смотрел через debug, при проверке в if на выходе получается нужное значение, а при записи в переменную - "".

Comment: Нет, код, который в указали в вопросе выдаст '3' '3' '3'

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Вы меня не правильно поняли, у меня уже так получается, только код функции другой.

Comment: если результат отличается, значит параметры другие.

Comment: @MrKan если у вас другой код и другие исходные данные, то что мы вам можем подсказать?

Comment: @splash58 Я вставил реальный код функции.

Comment: уже лучше. И еще бы несколько модельных строк файла. Только проверьте, что на них ситуация воспроизводится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы уверены, что после `f.readlines()` вы можете повторно читать файл с начала?
Варианты тут такие по вашему коду:

```
id_val = FindValue(self.asset, "ID")
if id_val != " " and id_val != "":
    self.ID = id_val
```

- Помещать значение `FindValue(self.asset, "ID")` в переменную и дальше использовать её в if и присваивании. Но дальше у вас всё-равно вылезут проблемы, когда вы ещё раз обратитесь к этой функции.
- Перед каждым чтением файла делать `f.seek(0)` (если это именно файл, а не какой-то поток без возможности перемотки).
- Сохранить куда-то содержимое файла и потом спокойно разбирать его содержимое столько раз, сколько нужно.
- Каждый раз перед чтением файла открывать его, читать, и потом закрывать.